# Python recursive generators performance

Tags: python, performance, recursion, generator

In python, when changing a purely recursive function into a recursive generator (not a plain generator) the performance seems to be degrading.

For example, here is a performance comparison between two functions which find all combinations of a list:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def rec_subsets(ms, i=0, s=[]):
    if i == len(ms):
        # do something with s
        return
    rec_subsets(ms, i+1, s)
    rec_subsets(ms, i+1, s + [ms[i]])

def gen_subsets(ms, i=0, s=[]):
    if i == len(ms):
        yield s
        return
    for a in gen_subsets(ms, i+1, s): yield a
    for a in gen_subsets(ms, i+1, s + [ms[i]]): yield a

t1 = dt.now()
rec_subsets(range(20))
t2 = dt.now()
print t2 - t1

t1 = dt.now()
for _ in gen_subsets(range(20)): pass
t2 = dt.now()
print t2 - t1
```

with the following output:

```
0:00:01.027000  # rec_subsets
0:00:02.860000  # gen_subsets
```

One would naturally expect **gen_subsets** to be approximately as fast as **rec_subsets** but this is not the case, it is much slower.

Is this normal or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to put some code in place of `# do something with s` before you can take meaningful timings.

Comment: Not necessary, gen_subsets is equally doing nothing. I did something similar in both cases just in case (adding to an empty global list) with the same results.

Comment: But why would you expect *adding* yield statements makes code faster?

Comment: Well this is what I am trying to know by asking this question in the first place, if this is a valid/warranted assumption. Recursive generators are very nice and versatile compared with pure recursion. It would nice if their performance was also good.

Comment: By the way, the original question is about performance, the edit doesn't serve that purpose.

Comment: IMO thats because of those loops in generator function. I think this makes gen and rec variants not equal.

Comment: For clearness you can make non-recursive analogs of two functions - first must generate list with all combinations, second yielding elements one-by-one. Second will be faster - not because of it is just a generator, but because a execution of function becomes _lazy_, and that makes generator more ffective in performance when it bounded with other code, which is doing something with results of work of generator.

Comment: I got a 10% speedup in gen_subsets by using the "yield from" statement, see PEP 380.

Comment: Gill Bates: your comment makes sense, can you please recast it as an answer?

Comment: Benchmarking should be done with `timeit`, not with `time`, for various reasons (timer resolution; correction for multitasking and other sources of variance; etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rec_subsets()` is still faster (for `range(20)`) even if `result.append(s)` is added inplace of `# do something with s` and the results of both `gen_subsets()` and `rec_subsets()` are consumed.

It might be explained by the following quote from [PEP 380 (`yield from` syntax support)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#optimisations):

> Using a specialised syntax opens up possibilities for optimisation
>   when there is a long chain of generators. Such chains can arise, for
>   instance, when recursively traversing a tree structure. The overhead
>   of passing `__next__()` calls and yielded values down and up the chain
>   can cause what ought to be an **O(n)** operation to become, in the worst
>   case, **O(n**2)**.

You could generate a powerset using [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

def subsets_comb(lst):
    return (comb for r in range(len(lst)+1) for comb in combinations(lst, r))
```

It is faster for `range(20)` on my machine:

```
name                    time ratio comment
subsets_comb        227 msec  1.00 [range(0, 20)]
subsets_ipowerset   476 msec  2.10 [range(0, 20)]
subsets_rec         957 msec  4.22 [range(0, 20)]
subsets_gen_pep380 2.34  sec 10.29 [range(0, 20)]
subsets_gen        2.63  sec 11.59 [range(0, 20)]
```

To reproduce the results, [run `time-subsets.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/5650097#file-time-subsets-py).

Comment: I think the lesson here is to substitute recursive functions with non-recursive generators for production code.